How I can fail VSTest@2 task in Azure DevOps pipeline if line coverage is below x %?
I want to force my Azure pipeline to fail if line coverage is below 60%.
It seems to be so easy. I already have the line coverage displayed in my pipeline results, but I couldn't find a way to force the VSTest@2 task to fail if line coverage is below 60%.:
Code coverage result displayed in my azure pipeline result
Can Somebody help me find a way to do this?
This my pipeline script:
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    runSettingsFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\Alper.SinergyIntegration.Tests.UnitTests\.runsettings'

.runsettings content file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>            
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>alpe.sinerintegration.application.dll</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>alpe.sinerintegration.core.dll</ModulePath>
              </Include>
            </ModulePaths>            
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>

My project is using net7.0 and xunit 2.4.2

No, you don't. Having arbitrary code coverage requirements doesn't improve the quality of your tests, it just introduces a hoop for developers to jump through. Having 60% code coverage isn't telling you anything other than people have attempted to exercise 60% of the code. It doesn't mean the tests are good, it doesn't mean the code tested doesn't have bugs. It's meaningless without context and analysis, and should never be something you gate builds behind.

Gonna have to disagree with Daniel.  Code coverage is a negative metric:  it tells you what your tests haven't done.  If your line/branch/expression/whatever is not covered, then I know with 100% certainty that you haven't tested it.  If your line/branch/expression/whatever is covered:  then I can't tell you what it means.

I partially disagree with Daniel: Having arbitrary code coverage requirements doesn't improve the quality of your tests, BUT code coverage requirements can push your team to at least try to test the code. Obviously, some parts of the code are more valuable for unit testing, and code coverage requirements can be applied to those ones.
